# Can Python threads work on the same process?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to come up with a way to have threads work on the same goal without interfering. In this case I am using 4 threads to add up every number between 0 and 90,000. This code runs but it ends almost immediately (Runtime: 0.00399994850159 sec) and only outputs 0.  Originally I wanted to do it with a global variable but I was worried about the threads interfering with each other (ie. the small chance that two threads double count or skip a number due to strange timing of the reads/writes). So instead I distributed the workload beforehand. If there is a better way to do this please share. This is my *simple* way of trying to get some experience into multi threading. Thanks

```
import threading
import time

start_time = time.time()

tot1 = 0
tot2 = 0
tot3 = 0
tot4 = 0

def Func(x,y,tot):
    tot = 0
    i = y-x
    while z in range(0,i):
        tot = tot + i + z

# class Tester(threading.Thread):
#   def run(self):
#       print(n)

w = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(0,22499,tot1))
x = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(22500,44999,tot2))
y = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(45000,67499,tot3))
z = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(67500,89999,tot4))

w.start()
x.start()
y.start()
z.start()

w.join()
x.join()
y.join()
z.join()

# while (w.isAlive() == False | x.isAlive() == False | y.isAlive() == False | z.isAlive() == False): {}

total = tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4

print total

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug that makes this program end almost immediately. Look at `while z in range(0,i):` in `Func`. `z` isn't defined in the function and its only by luck (bad luck really) that you happen to have a global variable `z = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(67500,89999,tot4))` that masks the problem. You are testing whether the thread object is in a list of integers... and its not!

The next problem is with the global variables. First, you are absolutely right that using a single global variable is not thread safe. The threads would mess with each others calculations. But you misunderstand how globals work. When you do `threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(67500,89999,tot4))`, python passes the object currently referenced by `tot4` to the function, but the function has no idea which global it came from. You only update the local variable `tot` and discard it when the function completes.

A solution is to use a global container to hold the calculations as shown in the example below. Unfortunately, this is actually slower than just doing all the work in one thread. The python global interpreter lock (GIL) only lets 1 thread run at a time and only slows down CPU-intensive tasks implemented in pure python.

You could look at the `multiprocessing` module to split this into multiple processes. That works well if the cost of running the calculation is large compared to the cost of starting the process and passing it data.

Here is a working copy of your example:

```
import threading
import time

start_time = time.time()

tot = [0] * 4

def Func(x,y,tot_index):
    my_total = 0
    i = y-x
    for z in range(0,i):
        my_total = my_total + i + z
    tot[tot_index] = my_total

# class Tester(threading.Thread):
#   def run(self):
#       print(n)

w = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(0,22499,0))
x = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(22500,44999,1))
y = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(45000,67499,2))
z = threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(67500,89999,3))

w.start()
x.start()
y.start()
z.start()

w.join()
x.join()
y.join()
z.join()

# while (w.isAlive() == False | x.isAlive() == False | y.isAlive() == False | z.isAlive() == False): {}

total = sum(tot)


print total

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a mutable object that you can add your results either with an identifier, e.g. `dict` or just a `list` and `append()` the results, e.g.:

```
import threading

def Func(start, stop, results):
    results.append(sum(range(start, stop+1)))

rngs = [(0, 22499), (22500, 44999), (45000, 67499), (67500, 89999)]
results = []
jobs = [threading.Thread(target=Func, args=(start, stop, results)) for start, stop in rngs]

for j in jobs:
    j.start()

for j in jobs:
    j.join()

print(sum(results))
# 4049955000
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.35 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted you could look `multiprocessing` in order to split the work to multiple different processes that can run parallel. This would benefit especially in CPU-intensive tasks assuming that there isn't huge amount of data to pass between the processes.

Here's a simple implementation of the same functionality using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

POOL_SIZE = 4
NUMBERS = 90000

def func(_range):
    tot = 0
    for z in range(*_range):
        tot += z

    return tot

with Pool(POOL_SIZE) as pool:
    chunk_size = int(NUMBERS / POOL_SIZE)
    chunks = ((i, i + chunk_size) for i in range(0, NUMBERS, chunk_size))
    print(sum(pool.imap(func, chunks)))
```

In above `chunks` is a generator that produces the same ranges that were hardcoded in original version. It's given to [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) which works the same as standard `map` except that it executes the function in the processes within the pool.

Less known fact about `multiprocessing` is that you can easily convert the code to use threads instead of processes by using undocumented `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`. In order to convert above example to use threads just change `import` to:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
```